# Do while loop Java language?

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

My program isn't working! I need it to randomly roll two dice, count the number of rolls until a Snake Eyes (2 ones) is achieved.
I feel like I am close, but my program will roll only ONCE, instead of many times until 2 ones are rolled.

The output I am getting is counted infinite loop of one single dice roll!

```
import java.io.*;

public class PA 
{
    public static void main (String [] args) 
    {
        int count = 0;
        int die1 = (int)(Math.random()*6)+1;
        int die2 = (int)(Math.random()*6)+1;
        int sumDie = die1+die2;    
        do 
        {
            System.out.println ("You rolled a:" + die1);
            System.out.println ("You rolled a:" + die2);
            System.out.println ("This is roll number:" + count);
            count = count + 1;
        } 
        while (sumDie > 2); 
        {
            System.out.println ("You rolled:" + die1);
            System.out.println ("You rolled:" + die2);
            System.out.println ("This is roll number:" + count):
            count++
        }
        if (die1 == 1 && die2 == 1);
        System.out.println ("Congratulations...Snake Eyes");
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us what you have so far. Please read how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Where's the actual code? :)

Comment: Apologies was having trouble inserting a screenshot ...one moment please!

Comment: No. Post the actual code into your post. Maybe you should also read [ask].

Comment: Don't use images to post code.

Comment: Okay I have it posted now! :)

Comment: Come on back guys...I need ya!

Comment: It's quite simple - you are rolling the dice _outside_ of the loop. A good way to find such bugs is to trace your program step by step.

Comment: I voted for reopening your question and reformatted your code. Now it should be _VERY EASY_ to fix your code by just looking at it, because the mistakes are easy to spot!

Comment: Do you mean... the do should be placed before the int die1(int)(Math.random...etc!???

Comment: @TerelleBrown your loop is waiting for `sumDie > 2` but you aren't setting sumDie within the loop at all. `count` is getting updated, but the loop will continue forever until `sumDie > 2` evaluates to true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the code that rolls the dice to inside the loop.
And, that block of code after the while is not needed.
And that last `if` - first it does nothing (has no body) because of the semi-colon. Second, not needed anyway, because the `while` condition ensures that to be the case.

```
public static void main (String [] args) 
{
    int count = 0;
    int die1, die2;
    do 
    {
        // New roll each time
        die1 = (int)(Math.random()*6)+1;
        die2 = (int)(Math.random()*6)+1;

        count = count + 1;
        System.out.println ("You rolled a:" + die1);
        System.out.println ("You rolled a:" + die2);
        System.out.println ("This is roll number:" + count);
    } while (die1 + die2 > 2);

    System.out.println ("Congratulations...Snake Eyes");
}
```